# Set two fields in one row in admin form magento2

Tags: magento2, admin, forms

I have created a custom form in magento2 admin via below code and it's working fine, but my form is too long, so I want to set two or more fields in one row And can divide fields in multiple tabs, Just like in Product edit form in admin. 
Here is my code-

```
   protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('booking_address');

    $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
        ['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post']]
    );

    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('address_');

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        'base_fieldset',
        ['legend' => __('General Information'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
    );

    if ($model->getId()) {
        $fieldset->addField('address_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'address_id']);
    }

    $fieldset->addField(
        'plz',
        'text',
        ['name' => 'plz', 'label' => __('PLZ'), 'title' => __('PLZ'), 'required' => true]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'street',
        'text',
        ['name' => 'street', 'label' => __('Street'), 'title' => __('Street'), 'required' => true]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'latitude',
        'text',
        ['name' => 'latitude', 'label' => __('Latitude'), 'title' => __('Latitude'), 'required' => true]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'longitude',
        'text',
        ['name' => 'longitude', 'label' => __('Longitude'), 'title' => __('Longitude'), 'required' => true]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'code',
        'text',
        ['name' => 'code', 'label' => __('Code'), 'title' => __('Code'), 'required' => false]
    );
    //=START=========Want to show these fields in new tab and two in each row==============


    $fieldset->addField(
        'sunday',
        'multiselect',
        ['name' => 'sunday', 'label' => __('Sunday'), 'values' => $this->getLocationTimes()]
    );
    $model->setData('sunday', $sunday);
    $fieldset->addField(
        'monday',
        'multiselect',
        ['name' => 'monday', 'label' => __('Monday'), 'values' => $this->getLocationTimes()]
    );
    $model->setData('monday', $monday);
    $fieldset->addField(
        'tuesday',
        'multiselect',
        ['name' => 'tuesday', 'label' => __('Tuesday'), 'values' => $this->getLocationTimes()]
    );
    $model->setData('tuesday', $tuesday);
    $fieldset->addField(
        'wednesday',
        'multiselect',
        ['name' => 'wednesday', 'label' => __('Wednesday'), 'values' => $this->getLocationTimes()]
    );
    $model->setData('wednesday', $wednesday);
    $fieldset->addField(
        'thrusday',
        'multiselect',
        ['name' => 'thrusday', 'label' => __('Thrusday'), 'values' => $this->getLocationTimes()]
    );
    $model->setData('thrusday', $thrusday);
    $fieldset->addField(
        'friday',
        'multiselect',
        ['name' => 'friday', 'label' => __('Friday'), 'values' => $this->getLocationTimes()]
    );
    $model->setData('friday', $friday);
    $fieldset->addField(
        'saturday',
        'multiselect',
        ['name' => 'saturday', 'label' => __('Saturday'), 'values' => $this->getLocationTimes()]
    );
    $model->setData('saturday', $saturday);

    //==END========Want to show these fields in new tab and two in each row==============

    $form->setValues($model->getData());
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

Please let me know how I can do this.

Thanks

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this Serialize

```
private $serializer;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface $serializer
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->serializer = $serializer;
}


public function execute()
{
    $options = array();
    $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
    foreach($post as $key => $option){
            $options[$key] = $option;
    }

   $finalOptions = $this->serializer->serialize($options);
   //Save $finalOptions in your db
   // $x->setData('rowname', $finalOptions)
   // $x->save();
}
```